# Connecting a photodiode in reverse bias to an oscilloscope

Tags: diodes

The attached photo is a diagram I wrote years ago when I was connecting a photodiode in reverse bias to my oscilloscope. Is this correct? The battery is a 9 volt. The photodiode is a from Thorlabs. It is FDS100 silicon PIN with a 10ns rise time. I am looking to measure light pulses in the 20ns range. I am not an electrical engineer so please keep that in mind when responding. Any information or confirmation is greatly appreciated. Thanks[image]

Comment: Is that a 50 ohm terminated scope?  If not, you will need to add a resistor or your detector will be very slow.

Comment: @user1850479 I’m not sure what a 50 terminated scope is. Mine is a Hantek 100 MHz., so I doubt it is. What size resistor would you suggest. Maybe a variable resistor?

Comment: Thorlabs has a webpage that goes over how to calculate the resistor size:  https://www.thorlabs.de/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=285  However, the 10ns they spec is assuming 50 ohms, so you should probably use that if you were expecting 10ns.

Comment: @user1850479 Thanks for the info. One last question:Should I put the resistor between the oscilloscope’s ground clip and the battery’s neg terminal?

Comment: Put the resistor from diode to the battery negative terminal. Then measure the voltage across the resistor.

Comment: These are very handy in this situation:  https://www.amazon.com/Copper-Adapter-38-5mm-Through-Terminator/dp/B07G566JC7/ref=sr_1_3  Few dollars gives you a 50 ohm scope, in which case you can just run a wire from the LED to the scope and not solder anything else.

Comment: @user1850479 Thanks I just ordered these. So now I can just connect like my photo shows and I should be go to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the recommended circuit from the datasheet:

[image]

Put your probe on the plus, and the ground on the -.  The noise filter won't hurt but is probably unnecessary with a battery as the power source.

And here is the formula for calculating RL:

[image]

The diode itself acts as a capacitor with 24 pF capacitance.  When you hit it with a photon, you get one electron of photocurrent, which flows through the load resistance forming a low pass filter with time constant R*24pF.  You need the resistor to convert the current into a voltage.  A larger resistor would give you a larger voltage, but you need the resistor to be small otherwise the rise time will be long.

If you plug in the recommended Thorlabs values, you will get that the rise time is actually 2 ns, not 10ns.  I have used this photodiode and it is in fact faster than the datasheet implies at 50 ohms, at least in all the units I got from them (perhaps they have different suppliers or simply didn't measure with a fast enoughs cope).  You could take a chance and use a 100 ohm resistor which will give you 2x the signal amplitude, or play it safe and use the 50 ohm resistance they recommend.

As requested, here are the calculations for that diode:

[image: specs]

Plugging in the values of 50 ohm and 24 pF gives a Fbw of 132 MHz and a rise time of 2.64 ns, or about 3.8 times faster than speced.  You could therefore use a 180 ohm resistor and get 3.6 times the amplitude (although the 1 nA of dark current will also lead to 3.6 times larger amplitude). This calculation doesn't depend on the intensity of the light source, but for a fast photodiode a relatively bright light source will be required for that bandwidth to have acceptable SNR.  For low light measurements you would use a source such as a PMT or APD that has intrinsic gain (more than 1 electron per photon).

Comment: The only problem is that a low impedance load is going to reduce the high frequency response when not using a pre amp of some sort...

Comment: @Hitek A low impedance load maximizes high frequency response since this circuit is an RC filter.  Making the R bigger would lower the cut off frequency.

Comment: I admit that I'm a digital guy and not very good at analog, but I thought I understood that the highest frequency scope probes available on the market are also the highest impedance probes.  Am I wrong?  The circuit that I just erased worked for me when testing a 48KHz IR input, but I admit the result was just barely good enough to count the pulses in a capture...

Comment: @Hitek This is a photodiode circuit, not an oscilloscope probe.  The reason the datasheet assumes 50 ohms is that they're not using an oscilloscope probe, they're just directly plugging the photodiode into a 50 ohm terminated scope.  You can use a high impedance probe too, but in that case you must add the resistor.

Comment: But his scope is not 50 Ohms terminated.  There are many schematics showing photodiodes feeding the input of high impedance op-amps in exactly the fashion I described and what worked for me.  I don't see how adding a 50 Ohm load is required, unless my resistor value just doesn't provide enough current for the diode to switch(I admit I didn't do the maths, but that's why I hate analog).  But like I say, I suck at analog, and I'm trying to get better every day!

Comment: Oh I just caught the part where you explained the rise time, which makes perfect sense.  I neglected to give consideration to the reverse biasing aspect and didn't realize that in this situation there was capacitance involved.  Thanks for the heads up, and I guess I have a lot more studying to do!

Comment: I was for some reason thinking about this completely in reverse. Of course it makes sense that lower impedance loads will have faster transition times, but how does that explain the fact that higher frequency probes are the highest impedance probes?  Sorry to the mods for abusing comments, but I'm done now...

Comment: @Hitek A 50 ohm cable can easily have many GHz bandwidth, but a 10 Meg oscilloscope probe is limited to a few hundred MHz so higher impedance is not required. Also, you cannot drive the high impedance inputs on an opamp with a photodiode. You won't get anything without a resistor. Look up transimpedance amplifiers.

Comment: Can you update with the recommended Thor Labs values??  I can't find them on their data sheet.  I would think it depends upon how much light you're trying to measure.

Comment: @ScottSeidman  Done. The bandwidth calculations don't depend on light intensity, but since that photodiode has 1 nA of dark current (6 electrons per nanosecond), you will need a nanowatt class signal to have an SNR greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

That is not right.  Your scope will always read 0.00V.  Also, you're fairly lucky that 9v doesn't exceed maximum reverse voltage.

The spec sheet for your part shows a recommended circuit.  Use it.

Answer (score -1):

I did this recently to test an IR transmitter.

20ns is half the bandwidth of your oscilloscope, so you should be good there.

Using your probe in 10x mode, try the following circuit.  You should set your scope for 10x, 5 or 2 Volts per division with DC coupling, and your sweep rate turned almost all the way up, with the trigger set to an appropriate level (or use auto trigger).  Note that this is a quick sloppy test circuit.  For good signal response, you should really use an Op-Amp for buffering:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWiUp5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: That isn't right.  You're measuring the reverse bias voltage of the diode, which is going to be 9V or very close. You need to measure the voltage across the resistor, which is also too large.